# Google Analytics autotrack Ajax not working in a jsf application

Tags: ajax, jsf, google-analytics

Google Analytics does not track ajax calls in a JSF web application. so I'm using [autotrack](https://github.com/googleanalytics/autotrack) here is the code:

```
<script>
        window.ga=window.ga||function(){(ga.q=ga.q||[]).push(arguments)};ga.l=+new Date;
        ga('create', 'UA-********2-1', 'auto');

        ga('require', 'cleanUrlTracker');
        ga('require', 'eventTracker');
        ga('require', 'impressionTracker');
        ga('require', 'maxScrollTracker');
        ga('require', 'mediaQueryTracker');
        ga('require', 'outboundFormTracker');
        ga('require', 'outboundLinkTracker');
        ga('require', 'pageVisibilityTracker');
        ga('require', 'urlChangeTracker');

        ga('send', 'pageview');
    </script>

    <h:outputScript library="custom" name="autotrack/autotrack.js" p:async="async"/>
    <script async="async" src="https://www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js"></script>
```

So When I click:

```
<h:commandButton id="nextBtn" value="Next" action="#{testBean.nextQuestion}" >
    <f:ajax execute="@form" render="pass-section title-section" onevent="go_top_and_apply_code_mirror" />
</h:commandButton>
```

and `go_top_and_apply_code_mirror`calls `ga('send', 'pageview')`. Except while I'm using the website clicking around, Google Analytics does not register me using the web page.

Chrome Console: shows this error

```
Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CONNECTION_CLOSED            www.google-analytics.com/collect:1
```

So what Am I doing wrong?

Comment: So you also tracked network traffic and noticed something very important there that you came to think it is related to JSF (in playing part in the problem, not something that is 'used'? Since client-side it is all plain HTML and Javascript and CSS...

Comment: no, just because I'm using jsf I taught I could be doing something wrong there so I point to jsf to too since I don't know what could be the problem